Qlik expression to DAX expression conversion
I need help in converting Qlik sense expression into a DAX expression.
Qlik sense expression:
if(sum(Total <AssociateEmail,RatingManager>{<flag_skill={1}>}RatingManager)>0, 'Initiated', 'Not Initiated')


AssociateEmail -- is from Table A
RatingManager,flag_skill -- is from Table B


pls provide some sample data and expected output

The DAX expression:
IF(
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table B'[RatingManager]),
        'Table B'[flag_skill] = 1,
        ALLEXCEPT('Table A', 'Table A'[AssociateEmail])
    ) > 0,
    "Initiated",
    "Not Initiated"
)


Thank you .. one doubt , why did you use all except function only for associate email field

It keeps the context of that column and removes filters from all other columns. You can delete that line if you'd like.

Thank You ...  Can you help me with below Qliksense expression "" if(sum(Total {<Priority-={''},flag_skill={0}>}[MSL/Med Name])>0 , 'Completed',
if((sum(Total {<Priority-={''},flag_skill={0}>}[MSL/Med Name])>0 or sum(Total {<RatingSelf-={''},flag_skill={0}>}[MSL/Med Name])>0 ), 'Initiated',
'Not Initiated')) ""   where Associateemail and Medname are coming from Tab1 and Ratingself, flagskill, priority coming from Tab2

I recommend you post that as a new question and accept this answered. This will bring your new question to a larger audience.
